# Is VBA needed for this?

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a data set organized as follows:

```
  Name      Begin      End
   A        2004       2004
   A        2004       2005
   A        2005       2005
   A        2006       2007
   .         .           .
   .         .           .
```

Suppose that there are  `26`  different names ( `A-Z` ). I want to count the number of times  `Begin = 2012`  for each  `Name` .

I could filter by  `Name`  and just type  `=countif(B:B, "=2012")` . But I would have to do this  `26`  times. Is there an easier way of doing this? Ultimately I want the output to be in the following form:

```
 Name       Count of 2012
  A
  B
  .
  .
  .

  Z
```

Answer (score 1):

What about Countifs?  `=Countifs(A:A,"A",B:B,"2004")` or is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: I would still have to type that in 26 times.

Comment: You don't have to type * 26 - you can just fill down the formula

Comment: @Trevor - as Tim points out, you won't have to type it more than once.  You can fill down the formula (there are various ways to do so). One way is to type the formula in a cell, then move the mouse cursor to the bottom right and you'll get a black square - click that and drag down, or just double click to fill down.